# Zio Zlayer unable to return as Interface or the implementation

Tags: scala, zio

I was writing some simple program using zio and was unable to get a Zlayer to triat type. If I remove the type added by intellij it is not compiling, but when removed its working fine.

I am new to zio and wanted to understand better. Thre code below is a very simple example and can also be found on scastie [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GXBrpLuzRPCZiE5e4udjIw)

I want a Zlayer which takes `A` and `B` and return `ABService`, which I am unable to figure out how.

I get compilation error for `serviceAB2` and `serviceAB3` and this compilation error is unfriendly and confusing.

And what is the return type of `serviceAB1`

```scala
import zio._

trait A{
  def run():Unit
}
case class AA(a:A) extends A{
  override def run() = println("A")
}

val serviceA = ZLayer.fromService(AA)

trait B{
  def run():Unit
}

val serviceB = ZLayer.succeed{
  new B{
    override def run():Unit = println("B")
  }
}

trait ABService{
  def run():Unit
}

case class AB(a:A,b:B) extends ABService{
  override def run() = {
    a.run()
    b.run()
  }
} 

val serviceAB1 = ZLayer.fromServices(AB)

val serviceAB2:ZLayer[Has[A] with Has[B], Nothing, Has[AB]] = ZLayer.fromServices(AB)

val serviceAB3:ZLayer[Has[A] with Has[B], Nothing, Has[ABService]] = ZLayer.fromServices(AB)
```

Comment: scala compiler can't handle some zio type magic without external help. You have to provide types explicitly from time to time. In your case, I guess you just need types in `ZLayer.fromServices[....]`

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko I get what you are saying. Let me try

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko looks like it worked. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem like a proper use of modules and layers in zio. I would recommend you to give a careful read to https://zio.dev/docs/howto/howto_use_layers.

Comment: @zagyi I totally agree, it's not recommended way, I am following the docs in my project, here I have simplified to illustrate my problem.